# Rails 5 : How to resolve Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production from vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbee in Rails trying to figure out how to use my image/css/js which is kept in vendor folder. I have created a fresh project kept one image under 
vendor/assets/images folder whose name is "sort.png" as per guideline assest folder will automatically search in lib/assets, app/assets and vendor/assets folder. but while running the server i am getting "Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production."

I m trying to access image link in view as

```
<%= image_tag "sort.png" %>
```

I have seen issue related to vendor in stackoverflow but everyone suggest to add 
configuration like Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) in assets.rb file which works for image . but how to resolve it for css and js .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `.css` and `.js` files in this list

```ruby
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += 
  %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif vendor/somefile.js vendor/somefile.css \
     vendor/bootstrap/*.js vendor/bootstrap/*.css \
     vendor/bootstrap/**/*.js vendor/bootstrap/**/*.css)
```

Comment: We are using bootstrap template which consist of so many sub folders which contains approx 20 js and css file how to include those thing in single line

Comment: You can also include folder `vendor/bootstrap/*.js`

Answer (score 0):

You also can add `//= link_tree ./vendor .jpg .jpeg .png .gif .svg .eot .otf .webp .ttf .woff .woff2` to your `app/assets/config/manifest.js`. It worked for me.

> Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives